# Spring boot doesn't call the handleAccessDeniedException() method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a global exception handler in my spring boot app that looks like this:

```
package com.springboot.blog.exception;

import com.springboot.blog.payload.ErrorDetails;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    //handle specific exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException exception,
                                                                        WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), exception.getMessage(),
                webRequest.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BlogAPIException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleBlogAPIException(BlogAPIException exception,
                                                               WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), exception.getMessage(),
                webRequest.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // global exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleGlobalException(Exception exception,
                                                              WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), exception.getMessage(),
                webRequest.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatusCode status,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String message = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, message);
        });

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException exception,
                                                                    WebRequest webRequest) {
        System.out.println("Called handleAccessDeniedException");
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), exception.getMessage(),
                webRequest.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


}
```

The security config file looks like this:

```
package com.springboot.blog.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                        authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());


        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails pavel = User.builder()
                .username("pavel")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pavel"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();


        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(pavel, admin);
    }


}
```

The problem is that when I login with incorrect credentials, spring boot uses the standard exception handler and doesn't call the custom handleAccessDeniedException() method that I have. Other exception methods from the GlobalExceptionHandler seem to work fine. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure authorization via security filter chain it's handled before your request reaches a controller, that's why `@ControllerAdvice` and `@RestControllerAdvice` won't work here.
With your set-up if you want to change the way Spring resolves denied access you should create your custom `AccessDeniedHandler`, which can do anything (like write straight to `HttpServletResponse response`), and pass it to security chain config like this:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                        authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer.accessDeniedHandler(yourCustomAccessDeniedHandler))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}
```

Or you can configure role-based or permission-based authorization using annotations like `@Secured`, `@PreAuthorize`, `@PostAuthorize` on your controller or service methods - then `@ControllerAdvice` and `@RestControllerAdvice` will work as expected. Don't forget to set `@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)` on your security config class in that case.